# CAPL PutValuetoControl

Tags: panel, capl, canalyzer

I am trying to display a message using PutvaluetoControl in Hex/Text Editor, but it is not working.

```
 on diagResponse Active_Steering.Active_Steering_Feb2021.DID_B526_Read
  {
    Write("PUT value into display panel");
    putValueToControl("NexteerDataWrite","DisplayStatus","DONE");
  }
```

NexteerDataWrite is Panelname

DisplayStatus is Controlname

What is the mistake in my code?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

putvaluetoControl works only with "CAPL Output View " it doesn't work with other tools of CAPL Panel designer.

Comment: Consider marking this answer as the solution to your question.